# PHP Prepared Statement Returns -1

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been using prepared statements for a little while now and I've never had any problems.

Now I'm trying to:

```
$sql="SELECT PhotoID,Caption FROM Photos WHERE EntityID=? AND TypeID=? LIMIT ?,?";

$iDB = new mysqliDB(); // Extends mysqli

$stmt = $iDB->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param('iiii',$entityID,$typeID,$minRange,$maxRange);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($photoID,$caption);

echo("Affected={$stmt->affected_rows}");
```

This prints -1.  I have triple tested that all 4 values in bindParam are set, and that the sql query works when pasted into myAdmin with the respective values.

Any idea what may be causing this?

Edit:: I found the answer online, apparently I need to use $stmt->store_result(); after executing.. but I am not sure it's needed now and never before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each mysqli function/method *can* fail. Depending on how you have extended `class mysqli` you probably have to test each and every return value. If a method return `false` an error occurred and the error message is stored in a property of either the mysqli or the statement object.

```
$sql="SELECT PhotoID,Caption FROM Photos WHERE EntityID=? AND TypeID=? LIMIT ?,?";

$iDB = new mysqliDB(); // Extends mysqli
if ($iDB->connect_error) {
  printf('connect error (%d) %s', $iDB->connect_errno, htmlspecialchars($iDB->connect_error));
  die;
}

$stmt = $iDB->prepare($sql);
if ( false===$stmt ) {
  printf('prepare failed: %s', htmlspecialchars($iDB->error));
  die;
}

$rc = $stmt->bind_param('iiii',$entityID,$typeID,$minRange,$maxRange);
if ( false===$rc ) {
  printf('bind_param failed: %s', htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
  die;
}

$rc = $stmt->execute();
if ( false===$rc ) {
  printf('execute failed: %s', htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
  die;
}

$rc = $stmt->bind_result($photoID,$caption);
if ( false===$rc ) {
  printf('bind_result failed: %s', htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
  die;
}

// echo("Affected={$stmt->affected_rows}");
```

Comment: Thank you, I never thought to debug this way -- I always assumed it was just the execute() that would commonly error

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [`mysqli_stmt->affected_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php):

> This function only works with queries which *update a table*. **In order to get the number of rows from a SELECT query, use [`mysqli_stmt_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) instead.**

So you can only use this method with an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` query.

Furthermore:

> Return Values
>   An integer greater than zero indicates the number of rows affected or retrieved. Zero indicates that no records where updated for an UPDATE/DELETE statement, no rows matched the WHERE clause in the query or that no query has yet been executed. **-1 indicates that the query has returned an error**. NULL indicates an invalid argument was supplied to the function.

But this could also mean that it returns `-1` because you try to use it for a `SELECT` statement. Try [`mysqli_stmt_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php).

**Update:**

Example form the page I linked to:

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER BY Name LIMIT 20";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* store result */
    $stmt->store_result();

    printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", $stmt->num_rows);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: I know this, but what error?  The statement is fine, and the values are correctly populated.

Comment: @pws5068: And what is the result when you use `mysqli_stmt_num_rows`?

Comment: Always zero, but maybe I'm using it incorrectly?
$stmt->execute();
die("Rows = ".mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt));

Comment: @pws5068: You are right about what you wrote in your question, you have to use `$stmt->store_result();` first: See the exampels here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php