# PHP MYSQLI Prepared Statement returns NULL

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a query that works in phpmyadmin however does not work in my code! I have tried various variable dumps to see if I have been loosing data before the query is executed, all seems ok, the same variables contents I have used in the successful query in phpmyadmin

To test I replaced:

```
$account_id = $account->getAccountId(); //output below
string(2) "59" string(4) "main" NULL NULL array(2) { ["id"]=> NULL["name"]=>NULL}
```

With

```
$account_id = 59; //output below
int(59) string(4) "main" NULL NULL array(2) { ["id"]=> NULL ["name"]=> NULL }
```

below is the code extract and I am using mysqli:

```
        $account = $Add_Profile_Image->getUserAccount();
        $account_id = $account->getAccountId();
        $status = $account->getType();
        var_dump($account_id);
        var_dump($status);
        $conn = $this->create_connection('read');
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT add_profile_images.image_id, image_name FROM add_profile_images, users_profile_images WHERE users_profile_images.account_id=? AND users_profile_images.status=?');
        $stmt->bind_param('is',$account_id,$status);
        $stmt->bind_result($id,$imageName);
        $stmt->execute();
        var_dump($id);
        var_dump($imageName);
        $result['id'] = $id;
        $result['name'] = $imageName;
```

I have replaced

```
image_name //in the query
```

To

```
add_profile_images.image_name //in the query
```

but the result is still NULL?

So I have tried the following examples in this post: [PHP Prepared Statement Returns -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549283/php-prepared-statement-returns-1)
When I dump the mysqli object it does return -1 however when I implement the below no errors 
are shown!

```
if($conn->connect_error) {
            printf('connect error (%d) %s', $conn->connect_errno, htmlspecialchars($conn->connect_error));
                        die;
        }
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT add_profile_images.image_id, add_profile_images.image_name FROM add_profile_images, users_profile_images WHERE users_profile_images.account_id=? AND users_profile_images.status=?');
        if ( false===$stmt ) {
            printf('prepare failed: %s', htmlspecialchars($conn->error));
            die;
        }

        $rc = $stmt->bind_param('is',$account_id,$status);
        if ( false===$rc ) {
            printf('bind_param failed: %s', htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
        die;
        }

        $rc= $stmt->execute();
        if ( false===$rc ) {
                printf('execute failed: %s', htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
                die;
        }
        $rc = $stmt->bind_result($id,$imageName);
        if ( false===$rc ) {
                printf('bind_result failed: %s', htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
                die;
        }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Hope someone can help!

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say the prepared statement returns NULL? Does the `$mysqli->prepare()` return NULL? Or are `$id` and `$imageName` NULL after `$mysqli->execute()`?

Comment: after the execute the bind parameters are NULL when they should be $id=(int) and $imageName = (String)

Comment: Have you verified that your query does return results? I think you may have some issues with your query anyway. You do an `INNER JOIN` on two tables, but never specify any join conditions. Did you intend to match every record in `add_profile_images` with every record in `users_profile_images`? There's nothing wrong with doing that if that's what you want, I'm just making sure you actually intended those results.

Comment: yes the image id (Pk) is referenced as the (FK) in users_profile_images the users_profile_images has a compound key with account_id and image_id. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: Defining a foreign key doesn't cause your joins to automatically match those fields - it's meant as a way to ensure data integrity. If you want to match rows in your tables on that foreign key relationship, you need to specify it. Something like this: `FROM add_profile_images JOIN users_profile_images USING( image_id )`

Comment: Thanks for the advice Ryan! do you know any good links for SQL queries?

Comment: Not really, I've been doing SQL for quite a few years now. You could try http://www.mysqltutorial.org and http://www.sqltutorial.org, but those are just sites I found in a Google search so I can't attest to quality or veracity. Also, I see you accepted jam6549's answer below - you should upvote it as well, especially since he is a new user. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to state $stmt->bind_result() AFTER $stmt->execute()
(see: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

Comment: Nice find. Also, Alan needs to fetch the data after calling `bind_result()`. `$stmt->bind_result()` specifies where to put the data, but you still need to call `$stmt->fetch()` until it returns null. See Example #1 on the linked page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jam6549, when testing for errors I moved bind_result under execute, result still NULL

Comment: Thanks I have added while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $result['id'] = $id;
    $result['name'] = $imageName;
   } @jam6549 and Ryan P Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same problem the reason for that is closing the connection when using the statement prepare. make sure, in your flow there is no such closing of the connection